# What do the colors in a terminal color scheme correspond do?

Tags: command-line, themes, colors

For example, if I go to [terminal.sexy](https://terminal.sexy/), I am able to design my own color scheme for my terminal of choosing.

What do each of these fields correspond to?

I can see that BG = background color, FG = foreground color, but what about the rest. What do values 0 to 15 correspond to, and how can I find this out?

I've noticed that for a lot of color schemes, the following format is given, but I don't know what any of the values pertains to. Is there some sort of documentation? I tried searching google but I don't know what exactly to be searching to get the right results.

What if I wanted to change the color of a comment. How would I know what number "comments" are?

[image]

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1375073.